# Can I create an if / else statement which compares variable type of user input in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was trying to make a simple Python program which gets a user input through the variable "user_input" and then it determines the variable type through the function "type()." Here is a sample of the code:

```
user_input = raw_input('Enter something: ')
if type(user_input) == 'int':
    print "integer"
elif type(user_input) == 'str':
    print "string"
```

So you see, the code prompts the user to type down something, and if what they type down is an integer, it will print "integer" and if the input is a string type, it will print "string". The code does execute without an error message, but when I type down either a string value or an integer, it prints nothing, no spaces, no messages, N-O-T-H-I-N-G. Here is an example:

```
>>>
Enter something: hello
>>>
```

So since it is not working, I have to ask, is it possible for Python to even compare variable types of a user input and then go through an if / else statement?

Comment: It prints nothing because both tests fail. The types are int and str, not 'int' and 'str'. Anyway it's not the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues.

Firstly, type returns actual types, not string descriptions of types.

Secondly, the type of the return value of raw_input is *always* a string.